# I can't connect to SQL Server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
class ContactsRepository : IContactsRepository
{
    private string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB);Initial Catalog=Contact_DB;User ID=****;Password=**********";

    public bool Delete(int ContactID)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DataTable SelectAll()
    {
        string query = "Select * From MyContacts";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        Sql command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(data);
        return data;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>
> Provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 51 - An instance name was not specified while connecting to a Local Database Runtime. Specify an instance name in the format (localdb)\instance_name.

Comment: Just `(localdb)` isn't a valid server+instance name - see the linked connectionstrings.com site for details - it needs to be something like `(localdb)\v11.0`. You can also create your own named instances in "local db" which you then need to specify in the connection string

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the code?

Comment: Instead of "(LocalDB)" in your connection string, use "(LocalDB)/something", where that "something" depends on your particular installation. It *is* running on your local computer, isn't it?

Comment: yes,it is running on my local computer

Comment: Side note: you really need `using` blocks on your connection and adapter objects

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the code?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2017/

Check here for correct connection string

and also you need "connection.Open()" before run command

```
public class PullDataTest
{
    // your data table
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public PullDataTest()
    {
    }

    // your method to pull data from database to datatable   
    public void PullData()
    {
        string connString = @"your connection string here";
        string query = "select * from table";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();

        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: But Visual Studio gives me error line 15 ***adapter.Fill(data);***

Comment: you need open connection thats why

Comment: @arhzw because Fill method does everything for you, like open the connection, run the query and then close the connection

Comment: @KamranMammadov there’s no need to open the connection explicitly with DataAdapter

Comment: Can you tell me how to write the code?

Comment: @arhzw i edited answer check there

Comment: I did all the things you said, but visual studio give me an error